# Find and Paste Value Between Sheets Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have part of a sub in Excel 2010 that’s supposed to search for a value in one sheet, find a corresponding value, and paste it into a master sheet. Then it does the same for a second sheet. There are two of these. In the first, i = 6, if it doesn’t find the second value in Column 10 (ie. 10 is empty), then it takes it from column 11. To give an example, say the first value in Master is Project 21. It searches 21 in Group 1’s sheet. If it finds it, it looks to column 10 for a value and pastes it into Master, or looks to column 11. Then it looks through Group 2’s sheet. I did it this way because I couldn’t get an If statement to work for checking each sheet (if proj isn’t in group1 check group2). The second one does the same, but with only the one column.

It isn’t working and it isn’t throwing any errors, and I’m not entirely sure where to go from here since I’m not overly familiar with VBA in Excel. Any assistance or suggestions for maybe a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
For i = 6 To 6
PROJ = Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1).Value

Set Found = Sheets("GROUP1").Columns(1).Find(what:=PROJ, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    PROJRow = Found.Row
End If

If Sheets("GROUP1") <> "" Then
    Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("GROUP1").Cells(PROJRow, 10)
Else
    Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("GROUP1").Cells(PROJRow, 11)
End If

Set Found = Sheets("GROUP2").Columns(1).Find(what:=PROJ, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    PROJRow = Found.Row
End If

If Sheets("GROUP2") <> "" Then
    Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("GROUP2").Cells(PROJRow, 10)
Else
    Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("GROUP2").Cells(PROJRow, 11)
End If

 Next

For i = 7 To 7
    PROJ = Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + 1).Value

Set Found = Sheets("GROUP1").Columns(1).Find(what:=PROJ, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
   PROJRow = Found.Row
End If
Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("GROUP1").Cells(PROJRow, 17)

 Set Found = Sheets("GROUP2").Columns(1).Find(what:=PROJ, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    PROJRow = Found.Row
End If

Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, StartColumn + i) = Sheets("Group2").Cells(PROJRow, 17)

 Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could do this with a series of nested "=IFERROR()" and "=VLOOKUP()" functions. Just nest them so that as each search fails it goes to the next search (or VLOOKUP) range.